# Laravel DD helper not executing inside each function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to troubleshoot my way through duplicating an object with its appropriate relationships. I usually use Laravel's DD helper to see if I'm getting the right information, but in this instance, I don't think that it's being run when it hits the line in the method that gets executed.

Here's my controller method that's handling the duplication.

```
        $copiedManagementSystem = $managementSystem->replicate();
    $copiedManagementSystem->inspections->each(function($inspection) {
        $copiedInspection = $copiedManagementSystem->inspections()->create([
            'name' => $inspection->name,
            'management_system_id' => $inspection->managementSystemId,
            'pass_score' => $inspection->passScore,
            'max_score' => $inspection->maxScore,
            'order' => $inspection->order,
        ]);
            dd($inspection); //I've placed the dd here but it doesn't work in any position, in any part of the each function.
        $inspection->checks->each(function($check){
            $copiedInspection->checks()->create([
                'question' => $check->question,
                'values' => $check->values,
                'type' => $check->type,
                'inspection_id' => $check->inspectionId,
                'order' => $check->order,
            ]);
        });
    });
    $copiedManagementSystem->save();
```

Here is the ManagementSystem's model with the inspections relationship

```
class ManagementSystem extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'management_systems';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

    public function inspections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Inspection::class);
    }
}
```

This is the inspection's model with the relations

```
class Inspection extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'inspections';

    protected $casts = [
    'order' => 'integer'
    ];

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'management_system_id', 
    'pass_score', 
    'max_score',
    'order'
];

    public function checks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Check::class);
    }

    public function managementSystem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ManagementSystem::class);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the check model with its relations.

```
class Check extends Model 
{
protected $table = 'checks';

protected $fillable = [
    'question',
    'values',
    'type',
    'inspection_id',
    'order'
];

    public function inspection()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Inspection::class);            
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help :)

***EDIT:*** So I've come across a strange occurrence. If I run the following:

```
dd($copiedManagementSystem->inspections->count();
```

It returns 0. But if I run:

```
dd($managementSystem->inspections->count());
```

It returns 12, which is the correct value.

Does anyone know why this happens? And if so, how can I fix the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: The collection you iterating over with each might be empty. Check this please first.

Comment: Hi Tacsiazuma, there are definitely items in the collection, do you perhaps have a method of how I could check this? :)

Comment: Try dd($copiedManagementSystem->inspections->count()) right on the 2nd line of your first snippet.

Comment: @Tuim, so that's returning 0. Looks like I have to figure out why nothing is coming back. Thanks for putting me on the right track! :)

Comment: Glad we could helped you out! An upvote on our comments would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Since replicate() does not replicate the relations you could try something like this.

```
$copiedManagementSystem = $managementSystem->replicate()
foreach($managementSystem->inspections as $inspection) {
    $copiedManagementSystem->inspections->attach($inspection->replicate())
}
```

It is pseudo code, if you want the original inspections linked remove the $inspection->replicate() call and just use $inspection

Same goes for any other relations $managementSystem might have.